# How to use slanger in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pusher

I want to use slanger in my rails app (in my php-App it works great), but I don't get any connection.

192.168.56.101 is my local Slanger-Server, I started it with :

```
slanger -k 123 -s 123 -w 192.168.56.101:8080
```

My config/initializers/pusher.rb

```
Pusher.url = "192.168.56.101"
Pusher.port = 4657
Pusher.app_id = 123
Pusher.key = 123
Pusher.secret = 123
```

My client-script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Pusher.host    = '192.168.56.101'
    Pusher.ws_port = 8080
    Pusher.wss_port = 8080

    var pusher = new Pusher('123');
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('test');
    channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
      alert( data.message );
    });

    Pusher.log = function(data) {
        console.log('\t\t', data);
    };
</script>
```

In my firebug-console I got this:

```
Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting
Pusher : Connecting : ws://192.168.56.101:8080/app/123?protocol=5&client=js&version=1.12.5&flash=false
Firefox kann keine Verbindung zu dem Server unter ws://192.168.56.101:8080/app/123?protocol=5&client=js&version=1.12.5&flash=false aufbauen.
Pusher : Connecting : wss://192.168.56.101:8080/app/123?protocol=5&client=js&version=1.12.5&flash=false
Firefox kann keine Verbindung zu dem Server unter wss://192.168.56.101:8080/app/123?protocol=5&client=js&version=1.12.5&flash=false aufbauen.
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> unavailable
```

Comment: I keep getting app key not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an iptables issue. *shame over me*

Comment: Hi, what change you have done in iptable? Why did you even need to change iptable in local server? Does port was closed? Can you elaborate? I am facing these issue for last 2 day.

Comment: I use puphpet.com for local testservers. In the new version they have iptables integration. When i'm back @home, I can send you my iptables :)

Comment: Thank you! Can you give the detail of iptables configuration, i am still facing same issue! Thanks in advance.